# How to generate a Twitter Bootstrap modal but keep it hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a Twitter Bootstrap modal, but keep it hidden until I'm ready to show it.

Here is the smallest amount of code to demonstrate. It successfully creates the modal, but it applies display: block to it inline, overriding my style.

```
    modalHtml = '<div class="modal fade" style="display: none" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">'
        + '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">'
        + '<div class="modal-content">Hello World</div></div></div>'

    modal = jQuery(modalHtml); 

    modal.modal('show');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx23xqbq/2/

I could add this

```
modal.modal('hide');
```

But this allows the modal to be visible for a split second.

How can I create a Twitter Bootstrap modal without displaying it to the user?

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `modal.modal( 'show' );` right away?

Comment: Why do you have this code modal.modal('show');? If you remove it, the modal will not appear.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh If I do not call `modal.modal('show')`, the modal will not exist. I need the modal to exist but not display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modals are hidden via the CSS class `.modal` by default.

Remove `modal.modal( 'show' );`.

You have `modal.modal( 'show' );` in your JS which causes the modal to be visible for a split second before you call `modal.modal( 'hide' )`.

---

Personally I would place the modal markup into the page before hand.

```js
var $button = $('button');
var $modal = $('#myModal');

$modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  // Optional. We update the modal with content stored in the data-content
  // attribute of the <button>.
  // You could also grab another hidden element to inject or perform 
  // AJAX here.
  var content = $(e.relatedTarget).data('content');

  $modal
    .find('.modal-content')
    .text(content);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Hi Guy!">Show Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" style="display: none" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Injecting into the page wouldn't be much different.

```js
var html =
  '<div class="modal fade" style="display: none" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">' +
      '<div class="modal-content">Hello World</div>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>';

// Append modal markup to page.
$('body').append(html);

var $button = $('button');
var $modal = $('#myModal');

$modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

  // Optional. We update the modal with content stored in the data-content
  // attribute of the <button>.
  // You could also grab another hidden element to inject or perform 
  // AJAX here.
  var content = $(e.relatedTarget).data('content');

  $modal
    .find('.modal-content')
    .text(content);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content="Hi Guy!">Show Modal</button>
```

Comment: If I do not call `modal.modal('show')`, the modal will not exist. I need the modal to exist but not display

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot place the modal in the markup to begin with? Or inject it into the page? You could hook into the following event `show.bs.modal`.

Comment: I've been instructed that using `modal.modal( 'show' );` to generate the modal is the preferred practice. While exploring this approach, I ran across this issue.

Comment: I've never heard/seen that before and don't believe that's in the [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target). Can you quote?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a Twitter Bootstrap modal without displaying it to
>   the user?

Technically you are already creating the modal with your first 2 lines of code. It just isn't displayed until the 3rd line (`modal.modal('show');`).

What I think you might be trying to accomplish is separating the code that creates the modal from the code that shows/hides it. The problem (I'm assuming) is that elsewhere in your code you no longer have a reference to the variable `modal` (that you created in `modal = jQuery(modalHtml);`), because it is out of scope.

Add this to your HTML page:

```
<div id="hidden-modal" style="display:none"></div>
```

Update your Javascript as described below:

```
modalHtml = '<div class="modal fade" style="display: none" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">'
    + '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">'
    + '<div class="modal-content">Hello World</div></div></div>'

// inject the modal markup into the hidden element on the page
jQuery('#hidden-modal').html(modalHtml);

// whenever ready, retrieve the hidden modal html and display it
jQuery(jQuery('#hidden-modal').html()).modal('show');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx23xqbq/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question this have to work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    draw();
  
});


function draw() {
  var html = ""
  html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>';
  html += '<hr />';
  html += '<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">';
  html += '<div class="modal-dialog">';
  html += '<div class="modal-content">';
  html += '<div class="modal-header">';
  html += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
  html += '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="modal-body">';
  html += '<p>Some text in the modal.</p>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="modal-footer">';
  html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
  
  $('#modal').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="modal">
</div>
```

When page is loaded the function draw() draws the modal and keep it hidden until you click the button, hyperlink, label or whatever you want.